# Oracle json query nested array

Tags: json, oracle, json-query

I would like to query this [json](https://gist.github.com/gpietro/889a608342307bdb309f52b7794429c5) example and select the questions.title and questions.answers[*].references[*].id (a string joined with "," is fine).

So far I end up with the following, using json_table, with no success with reference ids:

```
select key_v, title, refs
from ASSESSMENT a,
  json_table (ASSESSMENT , '$'
  columns (key_v FOR ORDINALITY,
    nested path '$."questions".*'
      columns (
          title path '$."title"',
          refs path '$.answers[*].references."eocnurse:interventions"[*].id',
      )));
```

**Desired result based on the example**

"Cambiamento dello stato cognitivo" - "247, 77253"

"Stato della circolazione" - "81, 24853608585"

"Sonno e riposo" - "24853608585"

The version of Oracle:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

**UDPATE**

I managed to modify the [json](https://gist.github.com/gpietro/11f07d3b171118befeb02c8a4da32812) data structure to be compliant with **JSONpath**.

With the updated json structure this is the solution to my problem:

```
select JT.*
from ASSESSMENT a,
  json_table (ASSESSMENT , '$.questions[*]'
  columns (
    "Title" PATH '$.title',
    "Refs" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR) FORMAT JSON WITH WRAPPER PATH '$.answers[*].references."eocnurse:interventions"[*].id'
  ))
  "JT";
```

Comment: You mention `json_query`, which is different from `json_table`. I assume `json_table` is what you really need. It would help if you would post the exact result you are looking for (or, if you are accepting any of several possible outputs, show or describe them all; if you have a preference for one of them, say so too).

Comment: Two quick observations anyway: First, the nested path should be `'$."questions".*'` (look at `title` for example - that is an attribute of a question, not an answer! - and in any case, "answer" is more deeply nested within the `json`). Second, the list of questions should be an **array**, not a list of unrelated attributes - this has to do with the structure of the `json` itself, not the query.

Comment: Yes, the nested path was wrong because I didn't update the example. Unfortunately I cannot change the structure of the data, and questions has to  be an Object with the question id as key.

Comment: The last part doesn't make sense. In your JSON, "questions" is not an object with the question id as key. Rather, it is an object with many attributes, one for each separate question. Each such attribute, in turn, is a single "question" object with the id as key - that part is fine, but the "questions" attribute should be an array. Otherwise the code (the json query) will still work, but it won't produce the desired result; it will just show the last reference id. That's how json queries are **supposed** to work, they can't fix wrong json structure.